# eth.sendTransaction successful or not?

Tags: web3js, ethereumjs

I sent 1 ETH on a private chain from node1 to node2.

```
>eth.sendTransaction({
from: "0x30278b135d0f5c10eb0684ff18bfd84912ae0f2b",
gasPrice: "5000000000",
gas: "21000",
to: '0xdba556d4250060d8be5abc82f50653430cee5769',
value: "1000000000000000000",
data: ""
}, 'password')
```

Result (TxHash)

```
"0xfd723065f3c389b91d379450caad235066762c53749780459218218ff9129205"
```

But when I check TxHash

```
> eth.getTransaction("0xfd723065f3c389b91d379450caad235066762c53749780459218218ff9129205")
{
  blockHash: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  blockNumber: null,
  from: "0x30278b135d0f5c10eb0684ff18bfd84912ae0f2b",
  gas: 21000,
  gasPrice: 5000000000,
  hash: "0xfd723065f3c389b91d379450caad235066762c53749780459218218ff9129205",
  input: "0x",
  nonce: 8,
  r: "0xbe40d0d29d00b48459ba36933eec4338065d2eb5511855316b8fa237c43c95ca",
  s: "0x568b749c609e9dfea9d35fad8e372a747a6eeedb58bbecd20103f8a2dd88cce3",
  to: "0xdba556d4250060d8be5abc82f50653430cee5769",
  transactionIndex: 0,
  v: "0x9c8",
  value: 1000000000000000000
}
```

And check the number of transaction of the recipient,

```
> eth.getTransactionCount("0xdba556d4250060d8be5abc82f50653430cee5769")
0
```

Was the transaction successful?

genesis.json

```
{
    "config": {
   "chainID": 1234,
   "homesteadBlock": 0,
   "eip155Block": 0,
   "eip158Block": 0
 },
 "alloc": {
    "0x30278b135d0f5c10eb0684ff18bfd84912ae0f2b": {
      "balance": "100000000000000000000000000000"
    }
 },
 "difficulty": "0x4000",
 "gasLimit": "0xffffffff",
 "nonce": "0x0000000000000000",
 "coinbase": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
 "mixhash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
 "parentHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
 "extraData": "0x123458db4e347b1234537c1c8370e4b5ed33adb3db69cbdb7a38e1e50b1b82fa",
 "timestamp": "0x00"
}
```

Transaction receipt:

```
> eth.getTransactionReceipt("0xfd723065f3c389b91d379450caad235066762c53749780459                       218218ff9129205")
{
  blockHash: "0x305262bbae04f2646d55724c4e87e836e558cc2c30bd874c2b2c768622113832                       ",
  blockNumber: 30198,
  contractAddress: null,
  cumulativeGasUsed: 21000,
  from: "0x30278b135d0f5c10eb0684ff18bfd84912ae0f2b",
  gasUsed: 21000,
  logs: [],
  logsBloom: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000                       00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000                       00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000                       00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000                       00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000                       00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000                       000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  root: "0xafbb5fe68186740e11cab692ad5c3b88a1b450cc27f93a2a627138a8a347d155",
  to: "0xdba556d4250060d8be5abc82f50653430cee5769",
  transactionHash: "0xfd723065f3c389b91d379450caad235066762c53749780459218218ff9                       129205",
  transactionIndex: 0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because `getTransactionCount(address)` returns the number of transactions **sent from** the address. You are passing the address which **received** the eth so its count will be 0. If you try with `0x30278b135d0f5c10eb0684ff18bfd84912ae0f2b`, it should give you `1`.

Comment: I tried but it's also the same. No transaction counted for both addresses.

Comment: Did you reset your local testnet by mistake? I just tried it myself and it works perfectly fine.

Comment: What do you mean reset testnet by mistake? I'm running a private chain with the genesis.json I just added above.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would not rely on `getTransactionCount` to verify if a transaction was successful. I would check the balance of the receiving address using `getBalance`.

```
> eth.getBalance("0xdba556d4250060d8be5abc82f50653430cee5769")
```

or, if you want to use web3 https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html#getbalance

Comment: Balance did not change for both addresses that's why I'm checking everything I can to find out what happened to the transaction

Comment: is the private chain set up correctly? are the nodes connected on the same network?

Comment: has the transaction been included in a block?

Comment: I added transaction receipt. I don't see any status field so it means it didn't go through?

Comment: Why would you not use transactionReceipt ? It literally is its purpose: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth.html#gettransactionreceipt